# How to sample a function non-uniformly?

Tags: pgfplots

See this example code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
                 xmin=-0.1,
                 xmax=1.1,
                 ymin=-1.1,
                 ymax=1.1,
                 domain=0:1,
                 samples=30
                ]
      \addplot[blue] {sqrt(x)};
      \addplot[purple] {-sqrt(x)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result appears acceptable far from zero, but near zero it's too much undersampled:

[image: result of the above code]

Increasing `samples` value makes the plot nice, but it considerably slows down processing. As a workaround I could just plot the inverse in a parametric plot (i.e. `(y^2,y)`), but in my actual code it'd require quite a bit of additional work.

Is there a way to provide a custom sampling function or specify different density of samples in different parts of the domain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`samples` and `domain` can be used as `plot` options and you can repeat same function for several domains. This is not a solution but more a workaround.
An example is shown as upper part (orange+blue) in following graph.

Another option (suggested by [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse)) consists in specifying samples with `samples at` option. This options follows a `foreach` (TikZ - pgffor) syntax. An example is shown as lower part (purple) below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
                 xmin=-0.1,
                 xmax=1.1,
                 ymin=-1.1,
                 ymax=1.1,
                 domain=0:1,
                % samples=30
                ]
      \addplot[blue, domain=0:.2,samples=30] {sqrt(x)};
      \addplot[orange, domain=0.2:1,samples=10] {sqrt(x)};
      \addplot[purple, samples at={0,0.005,...,0.1,0.15,...,1}] {-sqrt(x)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like a viable workaround, but still only a workaround. What if the function is more complicated? Do I necessarily have to copy&paste it?

Comment: Or you can go about it with `samples at={0,0.005,...,0.1,0.15,...,1}`

Comment: @percusse this looks like a completely another answer. If you posted it, I think I'd accept it.

Comment: @Ruslan. I've included percusse's solution.

Comment: It is my pleasure