# Gap when plotting Elliptic Curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to plot a elliptic curve with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2, xmax=2,
            ymin=-2, ymax=2,
            axis lines=center,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            samples=200]
            \addplot [blue] {sqrt(x^3 - x + 1};
            \addplot [blue] {-sqrt(x^3 - x + 1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Elliptische Kurve in der Form $x^3-x+1$ im $\mathbb{R}2$}
    \label{fig:Elliptische Kurve}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the plot]

My problem is that in the plot is a visible gap.
Does exists a solution for this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: related: [How to sample a function non-uniformly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297910/123129)

Comment: @dexteritas thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- Use `samples at` to define specific values that should be calculated and different sampling rates for different areas.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2, xmax=2,
            ymin=-2, ymax=2,
            axis lines=center,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            samples at={-1.3247, -1.32, -1.31, ..., -1.1, -1.05, -1, ..., 2.0},
            ]
            \addplot [blue] {sqrt(x^3 - x + 1};
            \addplot [blue] {-sqrt(x^3 - x + 1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Elliptische Kurve in der Form $x^3-x+1$ im $\mathbb{R}2$}
    \label{fig:Elliptische Kurve}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's working flawlessly!

Answer (score 6):

With a short iterative method, we see that (the nonnegative) branch of your cubic is defined for x ≥ −1.3247179572…

Using the method proposed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639053/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath-xfp}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{cubic}{1}{sqrt((#1)^3-(#1)+1)}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-2,
    xmax=2,
    ymin=-2,
    ymax=2,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    scale only axis,
    axis lines=middle,
    domain=-1.3247179572:1.5,
    samples=200,
    smooth,
    % to avoid that the "plot node" is clipped (partially)
    clip=false,
    % use same unit vectors on the axis
    axis equal image=true,
  ]
    \addplot [red] {cubic(x)};
    \addplot [red] {-cubic(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

No gap.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It helps me understand why the plot wasn't working the way I wanted it to.